# Generating an Excel file with AngularJS and WebAPI

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

This is the error that I am receiving when I try opening the Excel that is downloaded after being passed from the WebAPI to AngularJS.

> "Excel cannot open the file 'myfile.xlsx' because the file format or
>   file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been
>   corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.'

Here is the Angular call:

```
$scope.excelClick = function () {
            $http({
                url: 'Excel',
                method: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ selectedBrands: $scope.selectedBrands, selectedVehicles: $scope.selectedVehicles }),
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                responseType: 'arraybuffer'
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                var type = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
                var disposition = 'attachment; filename=vehicles.xlsx';
                if (disposition) {
                    var match = disposition.match(/.*filename=\"?([^;\"]+)\"?.*/);
                    if (match[1])
                        defaultFileName = match[1];
                }
                defaultFileName = defaultFileName.replace(/[<>:"\/\\|?*]+/g, '_');
                var blob = new Blob([data], { type: type });
                saveAs(blob, defaultFileName);
                //deferred.resolve(defaultFileName);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                //upload failed
            });
        }
```

And here is how I am passing it back from the API (table is a DataTable and is filled with data):

```
using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Vehicle Matching");
            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table, true);

            byte[] bytes = pck.GetAsByteArray();

            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes)
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "vehiclematch"
            };
            return result;
        }
```

I have tried many different things including changing the extension of the file, changing the type, the disposition.. but I still am getting this error every time it tries to open my file.

Comment: Could you check if the original file has the same length and characters then the one which is arrived to the AngularJS file?

Comment: The ContentLength of the response in the WebAPI is 2722. The byteLength in Angular is 273.